# Negative time complexity?

Tags: complexity, shors-algorithm

Just finishing an investigation into Shor's algorithm, and the following equation,
$$
O\big(\big(\log N\big)^2 \big(\log \log N\big)\big(\log \log \log N\big)\big)
$$
is given for its time complexity. However, this is negative for most small values, becoming 0 at $1\cdot 10^{10}$.

Why is this?

Comment: This is only 34 bits. Try 2^{128} or for RSA 2^{2048}

Comment: I get a root @ $e^e$. Strange. Ah - natural logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big O notations describes the complexity when $N$ approaching infinity, it is not a formula giving you exact running time for all $N$.

Roughly, let $f(N)$ be the function for the running time of the algorithm, the big O notation says that there exists $n$ and a constant $c$ such that 
 $f(N)<c\cdot (\log N)^2(\log\log N)(\log\log\log N)$ for all $N>n$.

Comment: And, as $n\rightarrow \infty $ equation $\rightarrow \infty$